# Are there any works of science fiction out there that relate to blockchain technology?

Tags: blockchain, pop-culture-references

It feels like science fiction is lagging behind Bitcoin and the blockchain technology that is powering it.  Are there any writers who have discussed similar technology in their stories? Even in the past 5 years?

See also the same question at [the ethereum forum](http://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/464/science-fiction-and-the-blockchain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found one: Stephenson's [Cryptonomicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptonomicon).

See also [Digital Currency: ten years before Bitcoin, Neal Stephenson's Cryptonomicon](http://www.laurelzuckerman.com/2013/03/digital-currency-ten-years-before-bitcoin-neal-stephensons-cryptonomicon-.html)

Answer (score 2):

[**Credsticks**](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Credstick) from Shadowrun by description work similarly to a Bitcoin hardware wallet, i.e. they are digital, but can't be double-spend. Yet, as far as I know, the mechanics are never explained in novels or rpg background material.

Answer (score 1):

See Karl Schroeder's "Eminence" in David Brin's recently published *Chasing Shadows, Visions of our Coming Transparent World*.

Comment: Could you please add a few sentences to explain how the book relates? (If it doesn't spoil the story.)

Answer (score 1):

Slow money in "Neptune's Brood" by Stross was interesting and relevant.

If thats not enough for you, pick an arbitrary altcoin whitepaper... :P

Answer (score 0):

You might like the short story [The Ghost of Gox](http://www.theghostofgox.com), about a hacker fighting autonomous software agents operating on the blockchain.

Answer (score -2):

The on going science fiction TV series *Almost Human* has mentioned Bitcoin in several episodes. [Video and Discussions](http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/news/bitcoin-featured-almost-human-tv-show-set-year-2048/2013/12/17). In the show, Bitcoin is considered as a well recognized way for anonymous money transafer. And 5000 btc will be a fortune the size of a country.